# when I sort pictures by name, some of them aren't showed

Tags: vba, excel

After insert pictures based on cell value, I put filters on header and when I sort by column "Nome",some imagens don't appear. Imagens are in diferente formats and sizes. Part of code I use is below. How to solve this?

```
Sub Imagens ()

Dim Path As String
Dim myPic As Picture
Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim myString As String
Dim rng As Range

 Set wkSheet = Sheets("Files Imagens")

    Set myRng = wkSheet.Range(“A2", wkSheet.Cells(wkSheet.Rows.Count, “A”).End(xlUp))

    For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
       myString = Path & "\" & myCell.Value

                   Set myPic = myCell.Parent.Pictures.Insert(myString)

             With myCell.Offset(0, 1)
                    myPic.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                    myPic.Top = .Top
                    myPic.Width = .Width
                    myPic.Height = .Height
                    myPic.Left = .Left
                    myPic.Placement = xlMove
            End With
        End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: When you insert your images make sure to set "move and size with cells".  If you record a macro while doing that you will see the code you need.

Comment: I tried this. When I use "myPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize", pictures don't move.

Comment: You might be stuck with having to run a macro after sorting to re-align any pictures which have gotten out of place.  There's no really dependable way to rely on Excel to do this for you when sorting cells with pictures positioned over them.  You can name your pictures on insert, so you can identify them based off the value in ColA

Answer (score 0):

Place values in column **B** as well as the images.  Set the font color in column **B** same as cell background color.

Then sort BOTH columns **A** and **B** by **A**

Comment: Hi, Gary, I tried this before, and nothing changed.